# Not show a message when checking years

Tags: angular

I have this function that generates years in an array older than current year. example. [2019, 2020, 2021].

```js
 getLastYear() {
    const startYear = this.org.createdAt.getFullYear();
    const now = new Date();
    const currentYear = now.getFullYear();
    const years = [...Array(currentYear - startYear).keys()].map(
      (e) => e + startYear
    );

    return years;
  }
```

In the my template am looping through this array to display each year in a clickable link like like this: 2019 | 2020 | 2021 respectively.

```html
<ng-container>
  <span *ngFor="let year of getLastYear()">
                <a [routerLink]="['.']" routerLinkActive="active" [queryParams]="{hmRange: year}" [queryParamsHandling]="'merge'">{{ year }}</a> |
              </span>

</ng-container>
```

And i have message in the html but i do not want to show the message when click on any of the years because those are older than current year

```html
<div class="alert alert-info custom-alert" role="alert">
  <div class="alert-items">
    <div class="alert-item static">
      <div class="alert-icon-wrapper">
        <clr-icon class="alert-icon" shape="info-circle"></clr-icon>
      </div>
      <span class="alert-text">
              <span i18n>There is not enough data to show this analysis. As soon as you have data in metrics, we will show this heatmap</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code that is responsible to show/hide the alert. With the current state of the code we can not help you.

Comment: Currently it only shows when there is no data  to show in a map so there's only a check to see if the map is emply like *ngIf="isEmpyty"

Answer (score 0):

The `year` in this case is dynamic, so you can either use [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#milestone-5-route-guards) or [router events](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent).

With Route Guard, you check if the current url has that param `year=`, if it has, block the whole route (page).
The same for Router events, where you listen for navigationStart event.